# Streamlit Dynamic Chart & Session State Issues

Tags: python, streamlit

I have written the following function that ideally allows users to display different types of charts and with differing x/y variables (or label/slice variables depending on the kind of chart). I've designed it to only show up in the Streamlit application when a user presses a button that triggers st.session_state["AS"] to be TRUE (see first 3 lines) and that defines a dataframe based on a function earlier in the code that runs a query against a database.

However, whenever I change the selectbox component values (ie chart type for example), the chart disappears...any thoughts on how to get it to persist? Appreciate patience here as I'm new to Python and scrapping this together as I go....

```
if st.session_state["AS"]:
    st.session_state["AS"] = True
    df = Query(st.session_state['generated_SQL'])

    # Main function
    def main():

        # Display the dataframe
        st.subheader("Data")
        st.write(df)

        # Select chart type
        chart_type = st.selectbox("Select Chart Type", ["Bar Chart", "Stacked Bar Chart", "Line Chart", "Scatter Plot", "Pie Chart"])

        # Select variables for visualization
        x_variable = st.selectbox("Select X Variable", df.columns)
        y_variable = st.selectbox("Select Y Variable", df.columns)

        # Check if x_variable or y_variable is a date field
        if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[x_variable]):
            df[x_variable] = pd.to_datetime(df[x_variable])
            df[x_variable] = df[x_variable].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()

        if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[y_variable]):
            df[y_variable] = pd.to_datetime(df[y_variable])
            df[y_variable] = df[y_variable].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()

        # Generate the selected chart
        if chart_type == "Bar Chart":
            generate_bar_chart(df, x_variable, y_variable)
        elif chart_type == "Stacked Bar Chart":
            color_variable = st.selectbox("Select Color Variable", df.columns)
            generate_stacked_bar_chart(df, x_variable, y_variable, color_variable)
        elif chart_type == "Line Chart":
            generate_line_chart(df, x_variable, y_variable)
        elif chart_type == "Scatter Plot":
            generate_scatter_plot(df, x_variable, y_variable)
        elif chart_type == "Pie Chart":
            labels_variable = st.selectbox("Select Labels Variable", df.columns)
            values_variable = st.selectbox("Select Values Variable", df.columns)
            generate_pie_chart(df, df[labels_variable], df[values_variable])
    
    main()
```

What I expect to happen is that when I press the button that triggers st.session_state["AS"] to be true, the resulting data frame from the query is displayed along with the default chart, and then the user can change the chart type and summary variables using the select boxes displayed on the application. However, when I change any of these select values, the data frame and the chart disappear altogether